# Does pulling the lever that honks the horn on Harbor do anything else?

Tags: gears-of-war-4

On the multiplayer map Harbor, there is a level that you can pull up near where the Longshot spawns (pictured below).

[image: Lever]

Is there a purpose to this lever other than honking the horn of the ship?  Is there a dynamic feature on this map that is triggered by it? I see a lot of people pulling it but nothing seems to happen.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You have to shoot 7 small statue in this map before pull the lever.

> After doing so, a giant fish-monster will jump out of the water!

For complete video how to do it you can watch [here](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=T9W97mqmShU&t=3m34s).